# Chrome incorrectly displaying WP login as 'not fully secure'

Tags: login, ssl

Any idea why Chrome (mac and windows) would mark a standard Wordpress login screen as 'not fully secure'? SSL certificate is working and correctly displays in Safari, Firefox and MS Edge. Checking the page on https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/ shows no insecure content. The login screen is uncustomised.

Comment: Hmm. It does not trigger warning in my browser. Using latest chrome version.

Comment: It might be a plugin, getting in there. If you open-up your Chrome console on the login page, there should be errors or warnings about which files are not loaded over https. I think you can also see those in the Network panel...

Comment: Thanks MacPrawn, console did it - it's the favicon! If you add that as an answer I can accept it. Cheers!